# MS-Access Pro Plus 2016 "Could not use '<path\file.accdb>'; file already in use" Win 10 Pro 64 bit v1909

Tags: ms-access

I have a Desktop: MS Office Pro Plus 2016 & Win10 Pro 64bit v1909, and also a Laptop: identical setup but different Office keys all fully activated.  MS-Access has started throwing an error (exactly same on both machines) since the latest Windows update.  This error is happening with a standard "Desktop Database" stand alone / not shared etc.

Whenever I try to Compact & Repair or File / Save As, MS-Access errors with-

"Could not use 'path\file.accdb'; file already in use".

This did not occur (on either machine) before the latest Windows updates.  It occurs for both new DBs and existing DBs.  I have tried: Permissions in the folder: I'm using an Admin Account and can read/write/update/delete etc-so no issues.  I've also disabled all Firewalls, Anti Malware to see if that was the problem - same error.  As the same thing has occured on 2 independent machines after the same Windows update, it makes me suspicious of that - has anyone experienced the same error or have any idea how to solve this?

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Kind regards,

Bob

Comment: You might try rolling back the update, and reporting this to Microsoft. Does this only occur when using _Save as_ or _Compact and repair_, or also in different circumstances?

Comment: Many thanks for the response.  Yes, I'd also thought of rolling back the updates, but there have been that many + all the Office ones as well that it would be pretty time consuming to do individually, then re-test each time to pin it down.  I have reported to MS, but it doesn't seem to be going anywhere with them.

Comment: This [MSDN forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/home?forum=accessdev)  seems to be a somewhat working way to raise attention for bugs. [Recent example](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/abd458eb-bf5b-4a89-b831-3d90e7e5d266/the-1912-update-to-access-20162019365-breaks-the-way-linked-sql-server-tables-with-identity?forum=accessdev)